# How can I prevent these value options delete by user when they fill in the inputbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

On page-reload it shows the value "SSS". If I select a option the value for each option shows up, but these options can be deleted. is there any option that these values can switch but can not be edited/deleted by the user?

```js
$('select[name=filter]').change(function() {
    var input_field = $('input#ifield');
    switch ($(this).val()) {
        case 'A': input_field.val('AAAAAA'); break;
        case 'B': input_field.val('BBBBBB'); break;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="filter" name="filter">
    <option id="A" value="A">AA</option>
    <option id="B" value="B">BB</option>
</select>
<input id="ifield" value="SSS" type="text" />
```

Comment: yes, you need to persist the data somehow (database, localstorage, cookie...) and retrieve the value on pageload to update the input

Comment: If I understood correct, you just set make your input `readonly`. This way you can change it's value with the script but the user cannot type anything in the input field.

Comment: Hi,  we do still need user to type in to inputbox next to the value, but do not want them to edit the value options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether a value matches the string at the beginning plus any string using a regular expression:

```
var reg = new RegExp(yourString + '.*');
```

For more infos on this visit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

I created this snippet to demonstrate:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select[name=filter]').change(function() {
      var input_field = $('input#ifield');
      switch ($(this).val()) {
          case 'A':
              input_field.val('AAAAAA');
              break;
           case 'B':
               input_field.val('BBBBBB');
           break;
      }
  });

  $('#ifield').on('input', function() {
      var A = 'AAAAAA';
      var B = 'BBBBBB';

      var select_field = $('select[name=filter]').val();

      //create regular expression for A
      var regA = new RegExp(A + '.*');
      //create regular expression for B
      var regB = new RegExp(B + '.*');
      if (select_field == 'A') {
          //check if the string doesn't match with
          //.test()
          if (!(regA.test($(this).val()))) {
              //set the value to A
              $(this).val(A);
          }
      } else if(select_field == 'B') {
          if (!(regB.test($(this).val()))) {
              $(this).val(B);
          }
      }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="filter" name="filter">
    <option id="A" value="A">AA</option>
    <option id="B" value="B">BB</option>
    </select>
<input id="ifield" value="SSS" type="text" />
```

Comment: we do still allow user to type in to the inputbox next to the value, but they can not edit the value option .

Comment: So like prevent the user from editing the sourcecode?

Comment: it like this, when user chose the option in select box the value appear in the input box and user can fill in detail in that box after the value , but that value is deletable/ editable.  so we want that value in the input box to be none editable when user filling in the inputbox.

Comment: thank you, as we / I can see here it working . but when i use these code as a test to my site it not working. it still the same that can delete.

Comment: Which browser (version) do you use?

Comment: i use Safari 5.1.7 and  Chrome Version 81.0.4044.138.

Comment: Make sure to put the JS-code after the HTML in the body.

Comment: Or you put the above code in a $(document).ready(function () {code here}); I've edited the snippet accordingly

Comment: I try the code, but when we select option B and filled in the inputbox the value auto changed to the value’s of option A , is there a way to prevent this happen. thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Just make your input hidden and display the value in some generic html tag.

html:

```
<select id="filter" name="filter">
    <option id="A" value="A">AA</option>
    <option id="B" value="B">BB</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="ifield" value="SSS" type="text" />
<span id="selected_val" style="color: #fff;">NOT SELECTED</span>
```

js:

```
$('select[name=filter]').change(function() {
    var input_field = $('input#ifield');
    switch ($(this).val()) {
        case 'A': input_field.val('AAAAAA'); break;
        case 'B': input_field.val('BBBBBB'); break;
    }
        $('#selected_val').html(input_field.val())
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/VladimirNT1/gup74h5r/2/